# differences when we add properties in extended class

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, express

I have this:

```js
class sampleError extends Error {
    constructor(message, errorCode) {
        super(message);         //Add a "message" property
        this.code = errorCode   //Add a "code" property"
    }
}
```

if i pass errorCode and message like that i add new properties. but what is the difference?

Comment: What's the difference between what and what?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much difference, basically just what function is adding the property to the object.

The standard `Error` function creates the `message` property using the message you pass it as an argument (if you pass it one and its value is not `undefined`).

Your function creates a `code` property by using the `errorCode` you pass it as an argument (whether you pass it one or not; if you don't, your code uses `undefined` implicitly).

Other than that, there's no difference, at least not according to [the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-error-constructor). (I *think* at one point one of the JavaScript engines defined `Error`'s `message` as an accessor property [and always had it, just with the value `undefined`], but I just checked and none of the major ones does that now. The spec makes it clear it should be a data property that won't exist if you didn't pass a non-`undefined` value into the constructor.)